# How to symbolically integrate a function of 6 variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, simplifying-expressions

I have a big function of 6 variables in total - `x1, x11, x2, x22, x3, x33`.

```
f6[x1_, x2_, x3_, x11_, x22_, x33_] := -((
3 (4 (x1 - x11)^2 - (x2 - x22)^2 - (x3 - x33)^2) ((x2 - 
x22)^2 + (x3 - x33)^2))/(
8 \[Pi] ((x1 - x11)^2 + (x2 - x22)^2 + (x3 - x33)^2)^(7/2)));
```

I need to use indefinite integral because i need to get a symbolic expression.

I am using Wolfram Mathematica 7.

I tried something very simple:

```
FullSimplify@
Integrate[f6[x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33], x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33]
```

I waited for about 30 minutes and nothing happened.
It is obviously a complicated integral.

****Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
Is there a way to simplify the function so the integration is easier for Mathematica?****

Comment: Try `FullSimplify@
Integrate[f6[x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33], {x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33}]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ulrich!
Mathematica managed to integrate it. However, I get a giant function with a lot of Assumptions and If statements. Also, it appears that integrated expression has both Real and Imaginary part, which is a bad news for me.

Comment: Without knowledge of your function it's difficult to give helpful answers!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have not been able to find documentation for your suggested syntax. Has this been changed in newer versions?

Comment: @Natas Sorry, please forget my comment. In this form integraion is done with integration variable `x1` in the range `x2...x33` and singularities `x2,x3,x11,x22`

Comment: Not related to your question but update MMa v7 to v12 and you'll be in awe.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the order of integration

```
Integrate[f6[x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33], x1 , x11, x2, x22, x3, x33]
```

the integral is evaluated in 120seconds.

Comment: Nothing is happening in my case.

Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: My version is v12 (Windows 10)

Comment: OK Ulrich. I appreciate your answers and effort!

Comment: Hey Ulrich. One more question.
Does the expression you get have any imaginary parts?

Comment: @user57225 Yes it's imaginary!  Sorry the expression is quite huge, that's why I couldn'd display it